# Better methods to apply operator "and &&" "or || " C++

Tags: c++, operators

Question: Is there a more efficient method to using operator or "|| " than what I'm using?

I'm creating the HangMan Game in which players type a letter and the only way to get out of the loop is by entering the correct word in which this case if statement is the only way out.

I'm running into a problem with my compiler, maybe is that i need to work on a better and cleaner version of my code but here is what I'm currently have so far...

```
// w is the word chosen
if(w1=='d' && w2=='u' && w3=='c' && w4=='k' || answer ==  error)
 {


  if(w1=='d' && w2=='u' && w3=='c' && w4=='k')
     {
     cout << "The word is correct \n";
     }
     else if (answer == error)
     {
     cout << " You got 5 strike you lost \n";
     }
 }
```

I'm currently using Qt Project Compiler in Ubuntu to Compile my C++ Program.

I don't have this error/ suggestion with Gcc g++ on the Command Line

```
/home/cristian/Qt_Programs/Hangman_Game/main.cpp:123: warning: suggest parentheses around '&&' within '||' [-Wparentheses]
```

Comment: Why don't you store the target word in a std::string and compare the input word against it?

Comment: When in doubt, add more brackets: `(w1=='d' && w2=='u' && w3=='c' && w4=='k') || answer ==  error`

Comment: The reason that you don't get the warning on the command line is probably that you didn't enable warnings (`-Wall`) on the command line. You're using `g++` as the compiler in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the first if statement. The second if-else will accomplish the same with or without it. That should remove the compiler suggestion.

```
if (w1 == 'd' && w2 == 'u' && w3 == 'c' && w4 == 'k') {
    cout << "The word is correct \n";
}
else if (answer == error) {
    cout << " You got 5 strike you lost \n";
}
```

Comment: It's not a real error by the compiler it's more of a suggestion but I think that option you just provided me was going on my head for a while is just that I was concern that it wouldn't caught any mistakes like the previous method but now that I think of it, it sounds more safer.

Comment: @Cris I fixed the answer. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: "In the comments somebody suggested adding parentheses. I don't think that will make a difference" It will make a difference in that it will remove the warning. The whole point of the warning is that the parentheses should be added for readability. Of course, as you said, removing the pointless `if` altogether is the better way to remove the warning in this case.